# Momentary Checkbox

Tags: manipulate, dynamic, gui-construction

I'm trying to create a demonstration in *Mathematica* where a checkbox will show an answer, but I only want the answer to be shown while the mouse button is pressed. There seems to be a `"Momentary"` option, but I can't figure out how it's used.

```
Checkbox[Momentary -> True]
```

seems to do what I want, but I need it in the `Manipulate` function.

Here's a simple example of what I'm trying to do:

```
Manipulate[
  ToString[x] <> " + " <> ToString[y] <> " = " <> If[a, ToString[x + y], ""], 
  {x, 1, 10, 1},
  {y, 1, 10, 1}, 
  {{a, False}, {True, False}, Momentary -> True}]
```

Doesn't work as I want. Replacing the last line with any of the following

```
 {{a, False}, {True, False}, CheckboxBoxOptions -> {Momentary -> True}}]
```

or

```
 Control[{{a, False}, {True, False}, Momentary -> True}]]
```

or

```
 Control[{{a, False}, {True, False}, CheckboxBoxOptions -> {Momentary -> True}}]]
```

doesn't do it either.

The documentation is very light in how `Checkbox` options are to be used.

Any ideas?

Comment: Where did you get that `Option` from? It does not seem to work standalone `Checkbox[Dynamic@x, Momentary -> True]`.

Comment: @Kuba It is an option of the underlying CheckboxBox and despite the red color it works for Checkbox[Momentary->True], without an argument or with argument True of False, but not if Dynamic is used as an argument. Therefore, my feeling is that this problem cannot be solved with a Checkbox alone and that you need an EventHandler or something like that, as in your solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a walkaround:

```
    Manipulate[
                x,
                Row @ List @ EventHandler[ Checkbox[Dynamic[x]], 
                                           {"MouseDown" :> (x = True), 
                                            "MouseUp" :> (x = False)}]
              ]
```